# Extra slash in url after 303 redirect

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, slash

I'm trying to redirect my website like `example.com/anypage` to `www.example.com/anypage`

This is what I'm using in my httpd.conf file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^example.com [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://www.example.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]
```

This redirects the page to `www.example.com//anypage`

How do I remove the extra slash?

Comment: [mod_rewrite behaves differently when used in per-server/virtualhost and per-directory configuration](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html): “In per-directory context (i.e., within `.htaccess` files and `Directory` blocks), […] the URL-path that mod_rewrite initially compares `RewriteRule` directives against is the full filesystem path to the translated filename **with the current directories path (including a trailing slash) removed from the front**.”

Comment: @Gumbo meaning I should use `http://www.example.com$1` as `RewriteRule`?

Comment: Either that, or you shouldn’t capture the leading slash.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://www.example.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]`

to:

`RewriteRule ^/(.*)        http://www.example.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]`